# Activechart.name is throwing 'out of memory' error every time

Tags: vba, excel

I have made multiple excel files trying to solve this problem. I have gotten to this point and am still getting an error for this function:

```
Sub graph1()
    ActiveChart.Name = IChart
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

This is in a macro enabled excel file with numerical-only data on Sheet 1 in the range A1 to F754 and a (manually made) Smooth Scatter Graph on Sheet 2.

Trying to run this code (with the chart selected to make ActiveChart effective) I am getting the error:

> Run Time Error '7':Out of Memory

Please help, I need to be able to name the chart so I can make .Axis formatting changes, re-size the chart, and some other things with a VBA macro.

Comment: Just a suggestion, try `ActiveChart.Parent.Name` instead of `ActiveChart.Name`.

Comment: I have tried the ActiveChart.Parent method already, the problem then is I cant do any of the resizing or formatting that I need to do. Like in the example below I receive a '424' Object Required Error, I need a setup so I cancreate, move, resize, and format the chart with the macro. But thank you for the help so far! Example: Dim ic As ChartObject Set ic = ActiveChart.Parent Debug.Print ic.Name 'retrieve chart object name ic.Name = "IChart" 'assign name IChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = -350

Comment: Do you need to have your chart embedded in a worksheet ? If you create a chart tab it's a lot easier - ActiveWorkbook.Charts(1) is the first chart, or you can refer to it by name like ActiveWorkbook.Charts("Chart1").

Comment: I have not tried that yet, thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try and get back to you, thanks @grahamj42

Answer (score 2):

How about assigning the variables something like the below, and making the changes as described:

```
Function test()

    Dim ic As Chart

    ' Somehow assign the chart to a variable
    Set ic = ActiveChart
    ' Change the name as desired
    ic.Parent.Name = IChart
    ' Change the axes as desired
    ic.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = -350

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Demetri I'll give this a try

Answer (score 1):

Don't mark this as answer since Demetri answered it correctly in the comments.
He is correct that you should use:

```
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "ChartName"
```

Or you can use a variable that contains your name.
Why use `Parent` property? The reason is `ActiveChart` points to `Chart` property of the `ChartObject` and you can only set the `Name` property on `ChartObject`.

So basically,

```
Dim Co As ChartObject
Set Co = ActiveChart.Parent
Debug.Print Co.Name 'retrieve chart object name
Co.Name = "Chart Name" 'assign name
```

I hope this clear things out.

Comment: I have tried the ActiveChart.Parent method already, the problem then is I cant do any of the resizing or formatting that I need to do.  Like in the example below I receive a '424' Object Required Error, I need a setup so I cancreate, move, resize, and format the chart with the macro.  But thank you for the help so far!  Example:
    Dim ic As ChartObject
    Set ic = ActiveChart.Parent
    Debug.Print ic.Name 'retrieve chart object name
    ic.Name = "IChart" 'assign name
    
    IChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = -350

Comment: @CompositeMan See Demetri's answer. You should work on the object. The name you assign the chart is not the object.